# how we can get the thumbnails from rss feed?

Tags: jquery, rss

i want to get the title and images from the rss feed to show on the page .i get the title from the rss feed but i can't get the images.please help me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function() {

    jQuery.getFeed({

        url: 'http://news.yahoo.com/rss/world',
        success: function(feed) {      
            var html1 = '';
            var html2 = '';
            var html3 = '';

            var item = feed.items[0];
            html1 +=item.image;  
            alert(html1);
            jQuery('#latestnews1').append(html1);

            var item1 = feed.items[3];
            html2 += item1.description;      
            jQuery('#latestnews2').append(html2);

            var item2 = feed.items[4];
            html3 += item2.description;      
            jQuery('#latestnews3').append(html3); 
        }    
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a rss reader library on the server side. Let the library fetch all the items. Then you can create an api to get all the items. Using a library insures that both RSS/ATOM are supported. Using your own code or regular expressions will not yield proper results. You might even get stuck with character sets.

In my case, I used [rome](https://rometools.jira.com/wiki/display/ROME/Home)